# Silverstripe - Include controller within controller

Tags: controller, silverstripe

I have a customer controller that has a form on it. What I want to do is add a form from another controller to the same customer page. Is there a way to do this in Silverstripe bar using an iFrame?

Comment: If you have an "Include" template for that form, you can include that from another template, yeah

Answer (score 1):

well, yes, but you probably need some modifications to your code.

there are 2 main approaches I can think of to accomplish your goal:

**1. separate the form creation from the controller action:**

```
class Foo extends Controller {
    private static $allowed_actions = ['FooForm', 'BarForm'];

    public function FooForm() {
        return new Form($this, __FUNCTION, new FieldList(), new FieldList());
    }

    public function BarForm() {
        return Bar::get_bar_form($this, __FUNCTION__);
    }
}

class Bar extends Controller {
    private static $allowed_actions = ['BarForm'];

    public function BarForm() {
        return static::get_bar_form($this, __FUNCTION__);
    }

    /**
     * A static function that accepts the controller (Bar or Foo in this case) and a name
     * This way, this form can easily be used on other controllers as well
     * Just be aware that this way, the Forms controller is not always the same, so if you have a custom form that calls specific methods of the Bar controller this will not work
     */
    public static function get_bar_form($controller, $name) {
        return new Form($controller, $name, new FieldList(), new FieldList());
    }
}
```

**2. nested controllers:**

SilverStripe allows you to nest controllers. This is essentially what Forms are already doing. A SilverStripe Form is a `Controller` (or rather `RequestHandler`).
In SilverStripe, any `Controller` action can return another `RequestHandler` (`Controller` is a subclass of `RequestHandler`) which will then be processed.

So you could return the whole Bar controller from within the Foo Controller and have it run as a child controller. So the URL might be `/foo/bar/BarForm`.
But with standard Controllers, I think you will need to do some tinkering to have nested URLs.

Take a look at my [ContentBlock/PageBuilder](https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-page-builder) module for an advanced example of nested controllers with Forms:
[PageBuilder_Field.php#L179](https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-page-builder/blob/4b89122ee292aa11390998ed9c0b0cfbd3bc8b41/code/PageBuilder_Field/PageBuilder_Field.php#L179)
[PageBuilder_Field_Handler_Block.php#L32](https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-page-builder/blob/4b89122ee292aa11390998ed9c0b0cfbd3bc8b41/code/PageBuilder_Field/PageBuilder_Field_Handler_Block.php#L32)